# Is it nonsense to not use Amplify API (and use the AWS API Gateway SDK instead)?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, api, aws-api-gateway, aws-amplify

i would like to know if i am the only one thinking to not use Amplify's API and instead use the classic SDK. The reasons are
1st: I am a beginner to AWS and development so the fact that Amplify is hiding the complexity isn't helping me to learn what's going on behind the scenes, control and understand everything well.

2nd: Can i modify the API without changing the generated to local project files? (files that generated while running "amplify add auth" command.

I am very confused about it, and can;t really find a guide of how to modify local files after doing changes to API through AWS platform.

Comment: Why do you think using Amplify over AWS SDKs is better?

Comment: I am making a react app so i have integrate Amplify for reasons like Auth and Iot(Pub/Sub) so i think is straight-forward to use Api throught Amplify. No?

Comment: For that use case - I agree. What AWS SDK to use all depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm just confused, for example when you run the "amplify add api" command,a folder named "api" is created on your project with the created lambda functions that you will create on creation  of api. Later if i want to add one m ore function or api path manually from user-interface how this will be updated also to my project's "api"folder?